# How can I collapse all html 'regions'

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Given a page (x.cshtml) that has many divs in the body, I'm wondering if there is a way to collapse the whole document? as collapsing down to [html] and then expanding to [body] and my target div is a lot quicker than collapsing each div individually.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery .hide() .show() feature

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm asking about the Visual Studio IDE, not how to hide a div via javaScript in a web page.